# Using image directly in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I tried a sample from the official docker blog:

https://www.docker.com/blog/advanced-dockerfiles-faster-builds-and-smaller-images-using-buildkit-and-multistage-builds/

In the section called "Using images directly" there is this dockerfile. When I tried to build an image, I got an error.

```
FROM alpine
COPY –from=linuxkit/ca-certificates / /
```

How do I use the image directly?

Comment: *What* error? That looks like a typo, shouldn't it be `--from`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, this is a typo. I need 2 dashes like this...

```
FROM alpine
COPY --from=linuxkit/ca-certificates / /
```

Images can be used directly as mentioned in the article!

Comment: This worked, seems like it still shouldn't!, where are you Copying from? in your COPY --from command?

Comment: @uglyCoder Yes. Copy all the files found at /* to / of current build. This is a very easy way to move files around.